# How to get all artists with NO videos and photos?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to get all artists with no content (videos and photos) uploaded. My query is missing the photos part. So far I have:

```
User.where(:is_artist => true, :is_verified => true).joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN videos ON videos.user_id = users.id').where('videos.id IS NULL').count
(8.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` LEFT OUTER JOIN videos ON videos.user_id = users.id WHERE `users`.`is_artist` = 1 AND `users`.`is_verified` = 1 AND (videos.id IS NOT NULL)
```

However, something with above query is slightly wrong, because:

```
User.where(:is_artist => true, :is_verified => true).count
```

Returns: 1000. And first query returns: 3000.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just curious, does `update_all` in the title have anything to do with the problem? Regarding the queries, in 1st case you perform left outer join that means for every user you get as many rows as the number of videos he has. Hence the difference in count result. And if you're trying to get users without videos it should be `videos.id IS NULL` instead (without `NOT`).

Comment: Nice try, but now title says 'artists with videos and photos' and in the question you're talking about 'artists with no content'. Which one do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all verified artists without videos like that:

```
User.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN videos ON videos.user_id = users.id').
     where(:is_artist => true, :is_verified => true, 'videos.id' => nil)
```

Comment: What about the photos part? The query needs to return all artists with no photos AND videos

Comment: Add another left outer join and another condition for nil photo id. Though, that might result in a pretty heavy query.

Comment: Also, your query above returns the same result set as my query, in my initial post..

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved simply by running

```
User.where(:is_artist => true, :is_verified => true).includes(:videos).count
```

if user have relation with videos

Comment: That will return all users (who satisfy conditions) no matter whether they have any videos or not.